# I'm trying to figure out how to change from one static variable to another in the inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

new game dev here. I'm not sure if this is a stupid question but I will ask it anyway. I'm trying to figure out how to change from one variable to another in the inspector. I have a few static variables in an empty game object called currencyMaster. Sorry if my question is hard to understand.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using TMPro;
public class currencyDisplay : MonoBehaviour
{


    private TextMeshProUGUI textMecH;

    void Start()
    {
        textMecH = GetComponent<TextMeshProUGUI>();

    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        //i want to change moneyPlus since all the variables are in 
        //currencyMaster
        textMecH.text = currencyMaster.moneyPlus.ToString("0.0");



    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, Unity only serializes public fields. In order to expose a private variable to the inspector, you need to mark it with the attribute [SerializeField](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializeField.html).

```
[SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI textMecH;
```